# plotting with Gridspec : index is out of bounds

Tags: python, matplotlib

I used a lot gridspec before, but today I have an error that I never had. Here is a code example, taken from pandas plotting example page:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts = ts.cumsum()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), index=ts.index, columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df.cumsum()

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 2), columns=['B', 'C']).cumsum()
df3['A'] = pd.Series(list(range(len(df))))

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(5,1)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6), facecolor='white')
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[:4, :])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[4, :])

df3.plot(x='A', y='B', ax=ax2)
```

While it is plotting all right, I have an error that stops the program:

> ---> 21 df3.plot(x='A', y='B', ax=ax2)
>
> IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

[image]

Note : `index 4` in the error message is directly linked to the gridspec limits. If I remove gridspec, the plot works well.

Pandas version :0.16.1

Matplotlib version: 1.4.3

Comment: Only the `matplotlib` part works for me using numpy ... which line raises the error?

Comment: I forgot some parts of the script... I just added them and the line that raise error.

Comment: works for me ... I have the versions: `pandas` 0.13.1 , `matplotlib` 1.3.1

Comment: Yes, as I was saying, it used to work fine. I updated my system yesterday and now the error message...

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem at pandas versions 0.16.2 and 0.16.1, I went back to 0.15.2 and that fixed it.